# Marking memos as read

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

I am putting together a site that handles H&S memos, and I need members to confirm that they have read their memos. I have looked at ways of handling this and they are based on assuming that members have read the memos the last time they logged on. I can't use this method as I need to assure their company that their workers have read their safety memos.

I have tried various ways of doing this but none are working well enough.

The main problem is selecting the correct ID number for the memo that they have clicked that they have read and then updating the details to the `memo_read` table. Any pointers, workarounds or solutions much appreciated.

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
$user_id = $user_data['user_id'] ;
$company_id = $user_data['company'];
$nothing = '';

$result1 = mysql_query ("SELECT `user`, `memo_id` FROM`memo_read` WHERE `user`= '$user_id '") or die(mysql_error());
$memo_id_query = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
$memo_id_query .= " AND `id`!= '".$row['memo_id']."'";
}

?>
<div id="memo">
<h7>These are your unread memos!</h7>
<table class="bit">
    <thead><tr><th>Title</th><th>Author</th><th>Time/Date</th><th>Memo</th></tr></thead>
<?php
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT `id`, `memos`, `author`, `time`, `title` FROM `memo` WHERE `worker`= 1 AND `company`='$company_id' ".$memo_id_query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))    {

   $id              = $row['id']; 
    $memo      = $row['memos'];
    $author     = $row['author'];
    $time        = $row['time'];
    $title         = $row['title'];
    global $id;
?>
    <tbody><tr><td><?php  echo $title; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $author; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $time;?></td>
    <td id="mem"><a class="toggle" href="#.bit" >read/hide</a>
    <div class="hiddenDiv" ><?php echo $memo; ?><br>
    <form id="tickmemo" action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="mark as read">
    </form>
    </div></td></tr><tbody>
<?php
}
if  (empty($_POST['submit']) === false) {
    $q=("INSERT INTO `memo_read` VALUES ('$nothing', '$user_id', '$id') ");
    $result = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
    }
?></table></div>
```

(edit)
This is working great now i'll put it up here if anyone else needs it or if you can suggest any tweeks!

```
<?php
$user_id = $user_data['user_id'] ;
$company_id = $user_data['company'];
$nothing = '';
$result1 = mysql_query ("SELECT `user`, `memo_id` FROM`memo_read` WHERE `user`= '$user_id '") or die(mysql_error());
$memo_id_query = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
$memo_id_query .= " AND `id`!= '".$row['memo_id']."'";
}
if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])) {
    echo 'You have marked that memo as read!<br>We will send you back in 3 seconds!';
    header("Refresh: 3; url=\"http://www.testbed1.tk/login/index.php\"");
    } else {
?>
<div id="memo">
<h7>These are your unread memos!</h7>
<table class="bit">
    <thead><tr><th>Title</th><th>Author</th><th>Time/Date</th><th>Memo</th></tr></thead>
<?php
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT `id`, `memos`, `author`, `time`, `title` FROM `memo` WHERE `worker`= 1 AND `company`= '$company_id' ".$memo_id_query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))    {

   $id              = $row['id']; 
    $memo      = $row['memos'];
    $author     = $row['author'];
    $time        = $row['time'];
    $title         = $row['title'];
?>
    <tbody><tr><td><?php  echo $title; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $author; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $time;?></td>
    <td id="mem"><a class="toggle" href="#.bit" >read/hide</a>
    <div class="hiddenDiv" ><?php echo $memo; ?><br>
    <form id="tickmemo" action="#" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="mark as read">
    </form>
    </div></td></tr><tbody>
<?php
}
$id = $_POST['id'];
if  (empty($_POST['id']) === false) {
    $q=("INSERT INTO `memo_read` VALUES         (''".mysql_real_escape_string($nothing)."'','".mysql_real_escape_string($user_id)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."') ");
    $result = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
    header('Location: worker.php?success');
    }
?></table></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a wide range of aspects here to comment on:

1. You have no input field "id" in your form, hence someone submitting the form cannot communicate what id they want to mark as read
2. You are assuming that register globals is on for the variable $id to be filled with a value. Instead use $_POST['id']
3. Your database queries lend themselves to SQL injection attacks, as you don't check any input. Use at least intval($_POST['id']) when saving to the database
4. mysql_query will be turned off in PHP5.5 I think, move to PDO
5. There is nothing wrong with doing it all in one file, but good programming style is to put the action logic at the top, output at the bottom.
6. If you need to scale the "read" table to a couple of 100000 rows, use [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4192/2599)
7. I think the business case is flawed as well. It will probably lead to people clicking memos as read, in the best case have them actually read, but not understood and memorized. It may be better to create a peer-to-peer quiz system to memorize the memos.

Comment: 1. I am trying to get the 'id' field from the while loop so the user does not have to add it, there is a button at the end of every memo, i'm trying to pull the memo id from the memo where the button is on.

Comment: 2. My bad the Global is left over from attempts to see get it working and i have tried to use $_POST as well but no luck yet :(

Comment: 3. The SQL isn't open to SQL injection attacks, as there is nowhere to put it, as there is no open fields or GET info.

Comment: Add <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>" />

Comment: 4 thanks for the heads up of the php5.5. when i have got it all working ok I'll sort that.

Comment: 6. I'll look into that thanks but in the end there shouldn't be that many rows.

Comment: 7. if they click them as read and they haven't then that is there fault.

Comment: Thanks jdog but i tried the "<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>" /> " and no luck unless i put it in the wrong place?

Comment: Jdog "SQL injection can be done from POST and COOKIE as well" ok the finished page will protect against that as well, but the people who will be using this will be builders so i don't think they will know anything about SQL injection, but i will add it anyway when i have finnished.

Comment: The attack vector of the builders would be to inject some javascript into their favourite fairly unsecure builders forum to launch the injection attack. These attacks are fully automated and part of a criminal value chain. There is the will, skill and money to make it worthwhile, no problem.

Comment: re <input field>, please update your script in the question. I'll be away soon, so can't answer until tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Your application flow it's not really clear. You should have:

1. A page where you list the unread memo to the user. Every list item should have a link that points to memo description page.
2. Memo description page - in this page you actually insert in `memo_read` table the `user_id` and `memo_id` which has been read.

Comment: Thanks i did have that in the first place but it was decided that the memo's would probably be small and not look good in a different page, so it was decided on this approach :(

Comment: Yes. but in this case you could easily choose ajax to make request to the server when a user read a memo. In the ajax request you would update that an user has read a memo